# What is "share-sheets" in Android Q?

Tags: share-menu, android-10

What is this feature and how is it better than the " Direct Share" feature, which was present in earlier versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this feature in a recent update to [FairEmail](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/releases) and thought of sharing (pun intended :-)

- [Getting Started with Sharing Shortcuts in Android Q](https://blog.mindorks.com/getting-started-with-sharesheet-in-android-q) has technical details but for users :

  - It's faster than Direct Share
  - > The new API uses a push model, versus the pull model used in the old DirectShare API. This makes the process of retrieving direct share targets much faster.
- [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/09/11/android-10s-share-sheet-smacks-down-apps-that-try-to-game-the-alphabetical-order/) says

> .... has new previews for links and images before sharing them, eight direct share targets, and four suggested apps on top, plus it uses a strict alphabetical order for apps....apps can no longer hijack the share sheet by naming their targets as "Add to" .

- From my experience in FairEmail, it shows contacts directly in the share sheet, so it makes it faster to share with a specific contact that you've been messaging recently. Favorite contacts become share targets (contacts with photos take precedence, which I believe is a feature from Android 8.1). The same behavior is shown outside of FairEmail, for instance if I want to share a Chrome page, these share targets appear first (without having to go through the mail app)

[Picture below](https://beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/android-p-vs-q-share-sheet.jpg) shows the difference. On the left is Share Sheet and on the right is Direct Share

[image]

(click to enlarge)