# How to share via mail always to the same recipient in one touch

Tags: automation, share-menu

I frequently share things by sending me to my gmail address. So I make 4 steps:

- tap share icon
- tap Gmail icon
- type my own address
- tap send

Is there a way/ app that automatize all these things : one tap on this app on share popup send directly "the thing" to a pre-parametrized recipent(s). ?

Comment: If you are on Android 10 and have an app that supports [share sheets](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222118/131553), it is possible but not with Gmail. [FairEmail](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2605/131553) supports it. I use that. All frequently mailed recipients turn up for sharing

Comment: Above only reduces one step - combines 2 & 3. That is the key. 1 is the start and 4 end. If you want to automatically do this, IMO, not possible

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have founded an app wich makes exactly what I want : share in 2 taps (not 1, it's true) : it's named [InboxIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lowenhardt.inboxit&hl=en_US)

With the free version, you can only quick share to your self gmail address, but it's largely sufficient for my usage !